# Opened port leads to a collection listing

Tags: server, macos, ports

I've been doing some searching on a macOS server and have noticed that there's an open port that I am able to access outside the network. When I go to this port it will ask for a username and a password, once logged in it provides a `Collection listing` that looks kinda like the following:

```
Collection Listing
   Name                   Size   Last Modified      MIME Type
.calendarsystem_version     1   2014-Jun-09 09:51   text/plain
.well-used/                 ?                       (collection)
addressblocks/              ?                       (collection)
user/                       ?                       (collection)
apns                        ?                       text/html
.calendars/                 ?                       (collection)
.directory/                 ?                       (collection, addressbook, directory)
principals/                 ?                       (collection)
timezones                   ?                       text/xml (timezones)
webcal                      ?                       (collection)
```

My only problem is, I have no idea what this is. It seems to be some sort of listing for development, from what I've gathered with nmap it shows as `8443/tcp open https-alt`.

I have two questions regarding this:

- What is this port open for/what is it?
- Would it be a good idea to close this port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is this port open for/what is it?

From Apple's support site [TCP and UDP ports used by Apple software products](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202944):

> 8443  - TCP - **iCal service (SSL)** -  pcsync-https
>     Mac OS X Server v10.5 or later (JBOSS HTTPS in Mac OS X Server 10.4 or earlier)

Thus, it looks like a calender service which explains names like `.calendarsystem_version`.

> Would it be a good idea to close this port?

This depends if you need this service or not.

Comment: That makes sense. So why is it open off the network is the real question than..?

Comment: @CertifcateJunky: likely because somebody has enabled the iCal service on the machine. Maybe a misconfiguration,  maybe intentional - ask the one who manages this system.

Comment: Awh, that makes sense. I seem to have found the issue. Thank you for helping!